# Create many duplicates of an image in python

Tags: python

I have an image in png format labeled pic1.png. I want to create a folder filled with identical copies of that image labeled pic1.png, pic2.png, ... pic100.png. How can this be done in python? I appreciate any useful code snippets.

Comment: Could you show us your attempt at it?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Check out the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) package.

Comment: @DanielWalker I think we should recommend an os agnostic approach like using shutil.copy(). But I agree with L3viathan that we should let him write some code before giving him a solution.

Comment: Thanks, the shutil package is just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
import shutil

for i in range(100):
    shutil.copy2('pic.png', 'pic' + str(i) + '.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use shutil!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pillow` like this:

You can install pillow by PIP: `pip install pillow`

```
#import pillow
from PIL import Image

#Load the image
img = Image.open('image.png')

#save 100 copies
for a in range(1,101):
    img.save('copy_'+str(a)+'.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it without importing any modules:

```
with open('pic1.png','rb') as r:
    pic = r.read()

for n in range(1,101): # Note that the 1 can be changed to a 2 because pic1.png is alrady there
    with open(f'pic{n}.png','wb') as w:
        w.write(pic)
```

That program will generate 100 duplicate images into the directory the python file is located.

---

---

If you want to generate them into a different folder:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\" # Path of the folder you want to store the copies

with open('pic1.png','rb') as r:
    pic = r.read()

for n in range(1,101):
    with open(f'pic{n}.png','wb') as w:
        w.write(pic)
```